# WPF + WCF + MVC + EF Web/Desktop Application

Tags: wpf, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am planning an application which will have a web based component and a desktop client component. Basically I am planning to create the web based component using `ASP.NET MVC3` & `Entity Framework` as a normal data driven website, however I am also planning to create a desktop client that will extend the functionality of the website, this is new territory for me and I am somewhat confused. I know that the best way to create an application that needs to access a central database is using `WCF`, however I have not used WCF before but have heard that it easily integrated with `Entity Framework`.

So I know that what I want to do is certainly possible I am just looking for some guidance for how the seperate components of this application should glue together, etc should I be working with `WCF` and `Entity Framework` first? Or should I complete the web based componenet before working with `WCF`?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this and all these ways have different level of complexities. For example, you could just build your web-application using Entity Framework, in the same web-application you expose an OData service (WCF Data Service) which provides a RESTful service that your WPF app can use to access the database. This is fairly easy, since WCF Data Services work really nicely with Entity Framework. This is basically a two-minute job (if you are not doing anything fancy). Your WPF application then has basically the same type of access to the database as your web-application does. In it's default configuration the WCF Data Service simply exposes a EF ObjectContext and allows the same type of operations on it. I would recommond you try this out and see for yourself if it fits your requirements.

But, this approach is basically a shortcut to allow a desktop application access to your database. Which in most cases, is perfectly fine. If you do want to put some effort into it, you could model a service-layer which either uses a Entity Framework data source or a OData data source. From here on in, it's all about design patterns. Which comes at a cost; separation of layers is a hard thing to do, if you want to do it right. Given that the .NET world as somewhat changed to "get the job done", it's fine to put those bits together and get a running app in no time.

You should also consider that the MVVM in WPF and MVC in a web-application have fundamental differences; where a MVC app just pulls a "snapshot" out of a database, a WPF application might need more effort and asynchronous programming to feel natural.

I can provide you with some guidance for specific tasks, like how to decouple the WCF Data Service and Entity Framework, but from my experience, the overhead of "doing it right" is enormous. If you are comfortible without a service-layer you will have a lovely experience working with EF and OData.

Answer (score 2):

It is better you start with the web component first integrated with wcf, you can use entity framework, but i would recommend using T-Sql itself if you have a data heavy DB and it gives you lot of options for performance.
I would recommend you build the application model using MVP pattern as it makes it easy to switch from a desktop to web application and also inline with your requirements of extending it.